# Spinner not showing selected item in android

Tags: android

I'm using Spinner in my Application, while resuming from another screen, it is displaying the first item in it, but the old item is selected. I'm using the following code, Any one please help me.

```
Spinner= (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
dataAdapter=null;
dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.
     R.layout.simple_spinner_item, country);

dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
Spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
if (myPrefs.getBoolean("isChecked", false)) {
    Spinner.setSelection(myPrefs.getInt("PreviouslyselectedID", 0));
}
else
{
    country.add(0, "Please Select");
}
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: I think you have missed calling the dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When adding item dynamically to the adapter, if not calling the:

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

selecting an added item would not be shown in the UI.

Comment: I was doing everything else perfectly, except for adding this line when dynamically adding. It worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

I faced same problem with fragment may be help to you,
Please try to add this line below the adapter set line,
Spinner.setSaveEnabled(false);